# How to add a progressbar to the android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to add a progress bar in the android webview based app. I have added following code but not working when tested.
Note: index.html have redirect tag which loads random URL. Everything is working fine except the progressbar.

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar Pbar;
    private final int ID_MENU_EXIT = 1;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);
               // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
         if (isNetworkAvailable())
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        else
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/404.html");

    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
              //get the MenuItem reference
        MenuItem item =
                menu.add(Menu.NONE,ID_MENU_EXIT,Menu.NONE,R.string.exitOption);
        //set the shortcut
        item.setShortcut('5', 'x');


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        //check selected menu item
        if(item.getItemId() == ID_MENU_EXIT)
        {
            //close the Activity
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

> Activity_main.xml

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/pB1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="2dip">
    </ProgressBar>

       <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Use this code for Progress Bar when your WebView waiting for loading WebView. :

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
public class MapActivity extends MenuActivity {

private final static String TAG = "HearingTest";
private WebView webView;
private String urlString;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

   context = MapActivity.this;

    urlString = getString(R.string.location_url);

    WebViewSettings();

    LoadWebPage(urlString);

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
            //progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                //Do something...
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (progressDialog!=null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

    task.execute((Void[])null);
}

public void LoadWebPage(String url){

    try {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        Log.d(TAG, "URL" + url + "connected");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "URL: " + url + " couldn't connect.");
    }
}

public void WebViewSettings(){

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(urlString)) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
             handler.proceed();
        }
    });
}

    protected void DisplayProgressBar(){

    }
}
```

Comment: The above code that I'd provided is fine. I've only issue with the progressbar. Please help me with that only.